# How much is the minimum moves that we put $n$ weights to another bar?

Tags: combinatorics

We have $3$ bars and $n$ weights.Weights are in one bar and we want to change their bar.The weights are ordered from bottom to top big to small.See the picture:

[image]

How much is the minimum moves that we put $n$ weights to another bar?

**condition1**:the bigger weights cannot stand on the smaller weights.

**conditon2**:You can change the bar of the weights that are in the top.

**My attempt**:We have three steps:

> 1.bring $n-1$ weights to another bar($f_{n-1}$ moves).
>
> 2.bring the biggest weight to the empty bar(one move).
>
> 3.bring the other $n-1$ smaller weights to the bar where the biggest is.($f_{n-1}$ moves).

From this we  can know:

$f_{n}=2f_{n-1}+1$

By solving this we can know:

$f_n=2^n-1$

THe answer in the test book is the same but I don't know how to prove it is the shortest way to do this.

Comment: Look up [Towers of Hanoi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TowerofHanoi.html). This problem is a classic. An inspiration to many puzzles, and lectures in algorithmic complexity.

Comment: Maybe you should add the condition that you can only pick one bar in 1 move because else you just can pick all of them at once and put them where you want.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a condition it is like a fact.

Comment: You should define (in the body of your Question) what a move consists of (apparently it consists of moving a single weight and never placing it on top of a smaller weight.  It does need to be spelled out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually asked: what is the minimum number of moves required for the [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Solution) puzzle with *n* discs?

The answer, of course, is $2^n-1$. There are many ways to prove it, but my favourite method is by means of diagrams like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tower_of_Hanoi-3.svg). The shortest path between starting and ending positions (grey points there) is obviously a straight line along one side of the Sierpiński triangle-like graph.

Comment: I need to prove it using the method upper.